# How could I get CGContextRef from UIImage?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgcontext

```
    CGContextRef context = ??; // get from UIImage *oldImage

    CGContextSaveGState(context);   
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, drawRect, newImage.CGImage);
    [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

In short, what I want to do is [ UIImage -> make some transform -> transformed UIImage].

Any ideas? Big thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// drawing commands go here
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Note that `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns an autoreleased UIImage instance.

Comment: Thanks, but what did I get a upside-down image even I did nothing?

Comment: If you use Core Graphics for drawing (e.g. `CGContextDrawImage()`), remember that it uses a flipped coordinate system. UIImage drawing methods don't require pre-flipping the coordinate system.

Comment: Noob question: This seems horribly wasteful... I just want to append a bit of data ontop of my image. I hate to redraw the entire thing for this.

Comment: @Ralphleon "Adding graphics on top" amounts to drawing and blending, which require the full power of the graphics engine.

Comment: @Costique I suppose that is the way I should think about it. It's the blending really... I always like to think of just "bits" :) Thanks for setting my mind right!

Comment: Is there a way to create a UIImage instance, then create a context that relate to this existing UIImage instance?